# Can you add a BarTintColor to React Native Router

Tags: javascript, react-native, router

Is it possible to add a BarTintColor to [React Native Router](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) as you can with NavigatorIOS?

Scenes have a `navigationBarStyle` property which allows you to set a colour with alpa: `navigationBarStyle={{backgroundColor:"#rgba(52,52,52,0.9)"}}` but not with the blur effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diving into the github code, no, there is no option to set a blur effect on the background.

But there's a solution to set yourself your Nav Bar : you can provide a component or set a function on the Scene's Component :

```
<Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login" navBar={myNavBarComponent}/>
// or ...

// In Login Component
renderNavigationBar(navBarProps, selectedScene) {

    // return CustomNavBar Component
}
```

If you want to achieve the blurred background effect of iOS, have a look at https://github.com/react-native-fellowship/react-native-blur#vibrancy-view.
You could then provide a custom NavBar with a blurred background effect.

Comment: I also think it's important that the renderNavigationBar method is static.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to blur effect on the background with the possible ones.